# Universal app to appear as an iPhone app in the app store

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, universal

We currently have an iPhone app and would like to make it look decent on the iPad without having to click the 2x button. We've coded it to be a "Universal" app but we do not want it to show up in the app store under iPad since this is just a stop gap until we have our full, separate iPad app.

Is there a way to launch this so it only shows up under iPhone but when a user launches this from their iPad it will render it properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

No, it's impossible.  A Universal app will automatically show up in both iPhone and iPad categories.

Answer (score 2):

Not Possible but you can submit it as an iPhone app.

1.navigate to project navigator

2.select your project

3.select target > your project's name > summary

4.change the devices from "universal" to "iphone"